# GCM same message received multiple times on server

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have implemented GCM CCS server-client architecture, which send upstream messages. This works perfectly but sometimes the same message is received multiple times. I searched on the web but I didn't find any good explanation for this issue. Does it happen when the cellphone has a bad connection that it takes some time to receive the ACK? What are solutions to make solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue and its caused because the same device has two or more Google registration ID, check your code validation to avoid this.

I'm not pretty sure in how much time but Google detects that the registration ID is really from the same device and proceeds to unregister to leave only one.

Comment: So the problem is that one device has more then one registration ID's? What did you do to solve this problem?

Comment: So possible solution is when A user changes his profile I call the unregister? So that could be a possible working solution?

Comment: Hi! excuse me i was pretty busy.  You have to store the  registration ID probably you are requiring sometimes a new registration ID, that will be the problem. And yes you can call GoogleCloudMessaging.unregister(), remember you have to wait some minutes to propagate.

Comment: But how is it possible that there are more reg id's are stored? I only can remember that only one id is saved in the preferences? How is it possible to send multiple message then from one device? Does Google save all the regid's that registered on that device? And they are removed at the side of GCM when you call the unregister? Are all reg id's removed then or just the last one?